# C- Segmentation Fault in strlen() for a word list problem

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, strlen

I try to create an extendable 20-letter-max word list. I use 'char word[20]' as a host for each new word before I add to the list. For inputs of words with length 20-, the program works fine. If I add a word with length 20+, my program should ignore, and continue.

But at the next time, I got Segmentation Fault somewhere at strlen(word) at those if-else statement.

Weird thing is sometimes my program can overcome this Fault, but for most of the time , it crashes.

Some attempts: 
- If I use 'char word[1000]' , it works fine in all times (so far). I guessed the argument pointer of strlen() mis-points to somewhere wrong after 'continue', so I tracked it with &word[0] and wrote strlen(&word[0]) and use 'char word[20]'. This doesn't solve the problem, and &word[0] stays the same when Segmentation Fault happens.

```
char *wordList[] = {""};
char word[10];
char * p, c;
int i = -1;
int size = 10;
int strlength = -1;

while(strlength != 0){
    //get word by using loop of getchar() and detect \0
    printf("Enter word :");
    scanf("%s",word);
    printf("Taken word: %s at %p\n",word,&word[0]);

    //detect word length to avoid 4-letter words and words with length 20+
    if (strlen(word) == 0){
        printf("Break due to length 0\n");
        break;
    }else if(strlen(word) > 20){
        printf("Ignore due to length 20+\n");
        continue;
    }
    printf("End checking length");

    //add word to wordList by extending memory for one new word and assign each char to memory
    i++;
    wordList[i] = malloc(sizeof(char)*strlen(word)-1);
    strcpy(wordList[i],word);
    printf("[");
    for(int j = 0; j <= i; j++){
        printf(" %s,",wordList[j]);
    }
    printf("]\n");
```

Comment: The address in of the first character In word,  `&word[0]`, is just `word`

Comment: `wordList` only has one element. `wordList[i]` has undefined behavior whenever `i > 0`

Comment: Are you that your wordList is a fixed length array of size 1. Trying to use it with any index other than 0 is undefined behavior. Undefined behavior could include strlen() segfaulting at some later time in your program.

Comment: When you call `malloc()` you need to add 1 to `strlen(word)`, to make room for the null terminator.

Comment: `strlen(word)` will never be `0`, `scanf()` always reads at least 1 character when you use `%s`.

Comment: And you declared `char word[10]`, if the length is 10-20 you have other problems.

Comment: Your word array is fixed length of size 10. Trying to put a string longer than 9 chars in it (including via scanf) is also undefined behavior.

Comment: @AviBerger You and I are thinking alot alike tonight. :)

Comment: You should use `%9s` to ensure that `scanf()` doesn't take in more than `word` can hold.

Comment: @AviBerger ya, the word might hold too many char and cause that fault, but what really happened in memory ?After holding a huge string, and continue the next loop, it doesn't fail right away when I scanf() and printf() a new nice word until strlen()

Comment: @DanielFarrell just experiment around. Lol . Look weird huh? Lol

Comment: "word" wouldn't hold the extra characters and they would likely overwrite something else. What depends both on your code and the implementation of the compiler you are using. I can't be certain of the exact details in your case. You could explore this and see how things are working by running your code under the debugger and examining memory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keep in mind that in C, strings are just continuous sets of characters in memory, starting with a known address (`char*` or `char[]` if you prefer), and ending with a null byte `\0`  C strings do not inherently know their size; *you* the programmer are responsible for making sure you don't attempt to access memory beyond that which was allocated your string.  When you do, you get a segfault.

```
scanf("%s",&word[0]);
```

You're telling `scanf` to read a sring from standard input and store it in `word` (`&word[0]` is just `word`).  But you don't tell `scanf` how many characters to read maximum, so you're not preventing `scanf` from accessing `world[20]` which is one character too far in a 10 character string (C is 0 based offset of course, so the first valid character in `world` is `world[0]` and the last is  `world[19]`.  ).  Enter more than 19 characters ( leaving one more for the terminating `\0`), and you'll overrun your memory allocation and anything could happen (if your program has valid data at that memory address, you'll overwrite it.  If data there happens to be a pointer, you'll overwrite the address and segfault the next time you attempt to dereference.  If your program's memory ends there, you'll segfault directly.

So what you have to do is tell `scanf` how many bytes to read maximum.  The easiest way is with the optional "field width specifier" for scanf:

```
scanf("%9s",word)
```

That tells `scanf` to read a string and store it in word, but only store up to 9 characters (the 10th is the terminating `\0` character).

> If I add a word with length 20+, my program should ignore, and continue

There's a flaw in your logic - you don't know whether the word is 10 characters long until you read *all of it* from input and *then* cound characters from `word` to the first occurance of '\0'.  Before you can check with `strlen` and optionally `continue`, you have already committed an error by writing the 11th character to `word[10]` within `scanf`.  Remember, it can't know from `word` alone how many bytes are allocated at that address.

The wordlist code has to be fixed too.

```
char *wordList[] = {""};`
...
//add word to wordList by extending memory for one new word and assign each char to memory
```

Well, `wordList[]` is exactly one `char*` long, and that string is `""`, the empty string you defined as the sole content of the statically defined list of unspecified length  `[]` whose size is determined at compile time to be 1.  Instead, you should just define your static list like you do for `word`.

```
char* wordList[20];
```

You'll also need to know the current list size, same as offset of the next list element.  You're already handling this; starting at `-1` and incrementing before the operation is a bit unorthodox but it works.

Now you actually *have* `wordList[i]` to allocate, until `i >= 20`.

```
unsigned int wordListLen = 0;
...
if(wordListLen >= 20){
   // list full!
   break;
} else {
   unsigned int wlen = strnlen(word,10)+1;
   wordList[wordListLen] = malloc( wlen * sizeof(char) );
   strncpy(wordList[wordListLen], word, 10);
   wordListLen++;
   ...print...
}
```

Don't forget a spot for `'\0'` when allocating for the copy of `word`!